# Android Wear release build aapt error

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to build the release version of an app including an Android Wear app.
When running the *assembleRelease* task for the mobile app, I get the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':MusicAppMobile:handleReleaseMicroApk'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\dev\tools\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My build tools, plugins and libraries are up to date. I already tried a clean rebuild.

UPDATE: Other things I tried without success in *build.gradle* for mobile and wear:

- minifyEnabled false
- shrinkResources false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the full command causing the error running *gradle assembleRelease --debug*.

> ...aapt.exe dump badging ...wear-release.apk

And the full error message.

> ERROR getting 'android:permission' attribute for service ... attribute is not a string value

I changed the service permission from a "@string/..." reference to the permission string constant. Now the build is successful. I guess the the string resource was removed in the release build process.